# Having an intransitive verb appearing before the subject

Tags: intransitive-verbs

[image]

The rule says, that you can not have an object after an intransitive verb. 
But this sentence, in my opinion, doesn't sound wrong? "Smiling was what the baby was doing."

But is it grammatically correct?

Comment: What do  you think the "intransitive verb" and the "object" are in your sentence?

Comment: Echoing the previous comment: how are you parsing the sentence, and why do you think the included graphic is relevant to it?

Comment: Where is the direct object in "Smiling was what the baby was doing"?

Comment: _Be_ is neither transitive nor intransitive in 'The baby was smiling' and related sentences.

Comment: The example sentence is in Engfish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you have restated the original idea not by changing its voice, but by converting the verb *smile* into a [verbal noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_noun) (traditionally called a "gerund") that is the subject of the main clause of the new sentence. Thus the example is grammatical, although quite awkward and unlikely to be uttered. It's the same pattern as if you said

> Cocaine was what the baby was doing.
>
> His income tax return was what the baby was doing.
>
> Seventy miles per hour was what the baby was doing.

If *smile* were transitive, you'd be able to use the passive voice to say something like *The mother was smiled by the baby*. But you can't, because it isn't.

Comment: Baby sure has been busy.

Comment: Except this quite precocious baby wasn't doing smiling.

Comment: Oh right, I am sorry. I completely missed the fact that I had converted smile into a verbal noun. Should I delete my question, as it is a bit misleading?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen If you think it might be helpful to other people who might make the same mistake, I would suggest you keep it, but if not, it's your question and you are free to delete it.